# Smoothness of a composition?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f(t)$ (complex function) is smooth in $t\in\mathbb{R}$, will $f(ul_0+vm_0)$ be smooth in $u$ and $v$? ($l_0$ and $m_0$ are two constants in $\mathbb{R}$--$t(u,v)=ul_0+vm_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by *smooth* ($C^1$, $C^\infty$?) but all sorts of differentiability-like properties are preserved under composition with linear maps.

Differentiability at $t_0$ means that there is $\alpha\in \mathbb C$ such that 
$$f(t)=f(t_0)+\alpha(t-t_0)+o(|t-t_0|),\quad t\to t_0$$
Plug $t=ul_0+vm_0$ here, and you'll get 
$$f(ul_0+vm_0)=f(ul_0+vm_0)+\alpha((u-u_0)l_0+(v-v_0)m_0)+o((u-u_0)l_0+(v-v_0)m_0),\quad (u,v)\to (u_0,v_0)$$
which means $f$, as a function of $u,v$, is differentiable at $(u_0,v_0)$.

Shorter answer: yes, the chain rule applies to your situation.

Comment: I meant $C^{\infty}$. Thank you for the detailed answer.